# Rejecting marriage proposal

Tags: nikah

Assalamuallaikum, is it a valid reason for rejecting a marriage proposal if one doesn't feel the connection with the person, like feeling no chemistry, and more of not liking the person in general. You know, that type of feeling, when you don't like a person for no reason.

And what if the person is into some kind of sickness as in Epilepsy. Is it ok to reject for that matter.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can it’s your choice and free will no one is forcing you if you don’t feel connections or feel like they aren’t suitable  for you, you can reject it.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This answer could use some elaboration and evidneces supporting yoiur cloiams. See also [answer].